# How to redirect already logged in users in ASP.NET via web.config?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, membership

I am using **Forms** authentication.

I created access rules.

Everything is OK, but I want to redirect users who already logged in to a specific page.

I know that I can do it via **code**, but I want to know how to do it via **web.config**?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to redirect users who are already logged in from the site landing page like Default.aspx or SignUp.aspx to another page like Account.aspx? Or do you want to redirect users visiting your login page if they are already logged in if they visit the login page?

Answer (score 2):

Try the defaultUrl attribute like this

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
 </authentication>
```

As explained in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)